# Modbus protocol for raspberry pi 2(master)

Tags: sensors, raspberry-pi2, modbus

I have an AQ-Alert+ (http://www.sstsensing.com/sites/default/files/DS0087_6AQAlert%2BDatasheet_0.pdf)
connected to a raspberry pi 2 via RS232 module. 
I am trying to send the datas fetched by AQ sensor (temperature, humidity, CO2, pressure and oxygen) to a server, using modbus protocol suitable for RS232.
Looking around the internet, all i could found was modbus protocol for specific sensors that use their specific libraries(like DHT22). But i need something general. I need to read the data from the sensor, and transmit it to a server.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [libmodbus](http://libmodbus.org) library.

I'm working on a swift wrapper. [Sample Code](https://github.com/LarsJK/libmodbus-swift-example/blob/master/Sources/main.swift)

Comment: are you sure about your syntax?

Comment: @SorinRadu what do you mean? If you tried and had issues with my wrapper please open an issue..